# Replace certain group by certain string

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-replace

I want to replace a string by different patterns depending on it format. For example:
The pattern `Y-m-d` should be replaced by `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`,
`m-d-Y` should be `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}` and so on.

I used `preg_replace()` two times for doing it. One for replacing `\m|d\` and another for `\Y\`.

```
$pattern = preg_replace("/m|d/", "\d{2}", $format);
$pattern = preg_replace("/Y/", "\d{4}", $pattern);
```

I want to know how can I do it by singe regex. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Provide sample input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_replace can act on array:

```
$pat = array('/m/', '/d/', '/Y/');
$repl = array('\\d{2}', '\\d{2}', '\\d{4}');

$pattern = preg_replace($pat, $repl, $pattern);
```